# How to save email "Messages" attachment using OpenPop

Tags: c#, console-application, openpop

I am developing a console application,where i want to download the attachment from mails coming to the Mail(only one account).I am able to download the attachment,if the attachment is attached to the mail directly,i am using OpenPop library.Below is the code to download/save the attachment.

```
Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();    
client.Connect("MailServer", PortNumber,UseSSL,receiveTimeout, sendTimeout,certificateValidator);
client.Authenticate(username, password);
List<Message> _messages = new List<Message>();
int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();             
for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
{
    _messages .Add(client.GetMessage(i));                    
}
string _path = @"D:\Attachments";
foreach (Message message in _messages)
{                  
    foreach (MessagePart attachment in message.FindAllAttachments())
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(_path, attachment.FileName);
        if (Path.GetExtension(filePath) == ".xlsx")
        {
            FileStream Stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter BinaryStream = new BinaryWriter(Stream);
            BinaryStream.Write(attachment.Body);
            Stream.Close();
            BinaryStream.Close();                                                
         }
     }
 }
```

But i am getting mails like,each mail is a collection of Messages and each Message has one attachment.
For Example: mail from abc@example.com,this mail contains list of messages,each message has one attachment,how to get this attachment.?
i tried   `var mailbody = message.MessagePart.MessageParts.FirstOrDefault()`; its not working.

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I don't know what tag you are referring to?

Comment: the `in C#` part of your title I removed 2 hour ago. It's not necessary to include that in a title since enlisted language tags are automatically included for searches.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Fetch-and-read-email-messages-with-attachments-from-GMAIL-POP3-mail-server-in-ASPNet.aspx) site. It has complete code explaining how to fetch and read email messages with attachments. Hope this helps.